# How to find weekend duration in hours using Carbon?

Tags: php, laravel, datetime, php-carbon

I'm aware that Carbon has weekend related functions, but that doesn't seems to work in my case.

I want to find the weekend duration in hour/minutes.

For example the weekend starts after 12:00 Friday and ends at 22:30 Sunday.

And the inputs be like :

```
 $start_date_time = new Carbon('2018-03-01 11:53:20');
 $end_date_time = new Carbon('2018-03-03 21:53:20');
```

What will be the best way to find the weekend duration in minutes ?

This explains it much better

```
        $start_date_time = new Carbon('2018-03-01 11:53:20');
        $end_date_time = new Carbon('2018-03-03 21:53:20');

        $total_duration =  $start_date_time->diffInMinutes($end_date_time); 

        $week_end_hours = //This is some thing I have to work out.

        /*

        My calculations is based on 'Asia/Kolkata' time zone
        For the given inputs

        2018-03-01 is Thursday // This is a weekday and no calculations required
        2018-03-02 is Friday //This is a weekend. So the duration needs to be calculated after 12:00
        2018-03-03 is Saturday //This is a weekend. So we need to calculate the duration till 21:53:20

        The result should be 2033 Minutes or 33 hours

        */

        $week_day_hours = $total_duration - $week_end_hours;
```

Comment: Would you care to post an example: example input with a result?

Comment: Updated the question. Check it please

Comment: I'm confused. This has nothing to do with weekends, really. You seem to just be looking for the difference between two DateTime objects, which is absolutely trivial in Carbon. `$startDateTime->diffInHours($endDateTime)`

Comment: Carbon has setWeekendDays([Carbon::FRIDAY, Carbon::SATURDAY]) but it's from Friday 12:00 AM to Sat 11:59 PM.

Answer (score 1):

Knowing the friday and sunday date:

```
$weekend_start_date_time = new Carbon('2018-03-02 12:00:00');
$weekend_end_date_time   = new Carbon('2018-03-04 22:30:00');
$start_date_time         = new Carbon('2018-03-01 11:53:20');
$end_date_time           = new Carbon('2018-03-05 12:00:00');

if($start_date_time>$weekend_start_date_time&&$end_date_time<$weekend_end_date_time){
    $weekend_time = $total;
}elseif($start_date_time<$weekend_start_date_time&&$end_date_time<$weekend_end_date_time){
    $pre_weekend  = $weekend_start_date_time->diffInSeconds($start_date_time);
    $weekend_time = $total-$pre_weekend;
}elseif($start_date_time>$weekend_start_date_time&&$end_date_time>$weekend_end_date_time){
    $post_weekend = $end_date_time->diffInSeconds($weekend_end_date_time);
    $weekend_time = $total-$post_weekend;
}else{
    $weekend_time = $weekend_end_date_time->diffInSeconds($weekend_start_date_time);
}

echo floor($weekend_time / 3600).gmdate("/i", $weekend_time % 3600);
```

Comment: This is something I was looking for. It's working for the pre weekend condition. What if there is post weekend days also. Let the end date be Monday afternoon 12pm.

Answer (score 1):

Based on @Iosu's if-else logic,

you can create weekend in the post date as well. Here's the code sample.

```
$start_date_time         = new Carbon('2018-03-01 11:53:20');
$end_date_time           = new Carbon('2018-03-05 12:00:00');
Carbon::setTestNow($start_date_time);// set the mock
$thisFriday = new Carbon('this friday');
$weekend_start_date_time  = $thisFriday->setTime(12,00,00); 

$thisSaturday = new Carbon('this saturday');
$weekend_end_date_time = $thisSaturday->setTime(22,30,00);
$total = 0;

if($start_date_time>$weekend_start_date_time&&$end_date_time<$weekend_end_date_time){
    $weekend_time = $total;
}elseif($start_date_time<$weekend_start_date_time&&$end_date_time<$weekend_end_date_time){
    $pre_weekend  = $weekend_start_date_time->diffInSeconds($start_date_time);
    $weekend_time = $total-$pre_weekend;
}elseif($start_date_time>$weekend_start_date_time&&$end_date_time>$weekend_end_date_time){
    $post_weekend = $end_date_time->diffInSeconds($weekend_end_date_time);
    $weekend_time = $total-$post_weekend;
}else{
    $weekend_time = $weekend_end_date_time->diffInSeconds($weekend_start_date_time);
}

echo floor($weekend_time / 3600).gmdate("/i", $weekend_time % 3600);
Carbon::setTestNow();
```

Give it a try!

Note: not tested if-else logic part.